# MSMQ System.Messaging high resource usage

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, msmq

I have make C# console application which uses timer which connects to MSMQ every 10 seconds get data insert into Oracle database. But the issue is that it log in and log off to domain and create high CPU also create security audit log very much which waste my resources.

My console application runs with task schedule. Code is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Messaging;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client; 
using System.Data;


namespace MSMQ_News
{
    class Program
    {
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(60000);//10000
            // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
            // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
            //aTimer.Interval = 10000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            aTimer.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(" From Main -- " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Just in case someone wants to inherit your class and lock it as well ...
        object _padlock = new object();
        try
        {
            aTimer.Stop();
            lock (_padlock)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
                ProcessQueueMsgs();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(" From OnTimedEvent -- " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            aTimer.Start();
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessQueueMsgs()
    {
        try
        {
            while ((DateTime.Now.Hour >= 06)
                && (DateTime.Now.Hour <= 16))
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                ReceiveNewsDetail(dt);
                ReceiveNewsHeader(dt);
            }
            CloseApp();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(" From ProcessQueueMsgs -- " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static bool QueueExist(string QueueName)
    {
        try
        {
            if (MessageQueue.Exists(QueueName))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(" From QueueExist -- " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveNewsHeader(DateTime dt)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageQueue mqNewsHeader = null;
            string value = "", _tmp = "";
            _tmp = "<newsHeader></newsHeader> ";
            /*if (QueueExist(@".\q_ws_ampnewsheaderrep"))*/
            mqNewsHeader = new MessageQueue(@".\q_ws_ampnewsheaderrep");

            int MsgCount = GetMessageCount(mqNewsHeader, @".\q_ws_ampnewsheaderrep");
            for (int i = 0; i < MsgCount; i++)
            {
                Message Msg = mqNewsHeader.Receive();
                Msg.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();

                //need to do this to avoid ??? for arabic characters
                using (StreamReader strdr = new StreamReader(Msg.BodyStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
                {
                    value = strdr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                value = value.Replace("\0", String.Empty);
                if (value != _tmp)
                {
                    LoadNewsHeader(value, dt);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("From ReceiveNewsHeader -- " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveNewsDetail(DateTime dt)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageQueue mqNewsDetails = null;
            string value = "", _tmp = "";
            _tmp = "<news></news> ";
            /*if (QueueExist(@".\q_ws_ampnewsrep"))*/
                mqNewsDetails = new MessageQueue(@".\q_ws_ampnewsrep");

            int MsgCount = GetMessageCount(mqNewsDetails, @".\q_ws_ampnewsrep");
            for (int i = 0; i < MsgCount; i++)
            {
                Message Msg = mqNewsDetails.Receive();
                Msg.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();

                //need to do this to avoid ??? for arabic characters
                using (StreamReader strdr = new StreamReader(Msg.BodyStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
                {
                    value = strdr.ReadToEnd();
                }

                value = value.Replace("\0", String.Empty);
                if (value != _tmp)
                {
                    LoadNewsDetail(value, dt);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("From ReceiveNewsDetail -- " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void LoadNewsHeader(string text , DateTime dt)
    {
        try
        {

            //text = ReplaceSpecialCharacters(text);
            //text = Clean(text);
            //XmlDocument _xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            //_xmlDoc.LoadXml(text);
            //string fileName = "NewsHeader.xml";
            text = text.Replace("<arabicFields>", "<arabicFields>\n\t\t");

            //createXMLFile(fileName, text);
            XmlDocument _xmlDoc = LoadXMLDoc(text);

            string SQL = "";


            XmlNodeList newsHeaderList = _xmlDoc.SelectNodes("newsHeader/newsHeaderRep");
            if (newsHeaderList.Count > 0)
            {
                OracleParameter pTRUNCATE = new OracleParameter("P_TABLE_NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                pTRUNCATE.Value = "COMPANIES_NEWS";
                DatabaseOperation(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "TRUNCATE_TABLE", pTRUNCATE);
            }
            foreach (XmlNode news in newsHeaderList)
            {

                XmlNodeList newsIdList = news.SelectNodes("newsId");
                SQL = "Insert into COMPANIES_NEWS(NewsID, NewsID_SEQNO, NEWSSTATUS, LANGUAGE_CD, SEC_CD, RELEASEDATE, RELEASETIME, TITLE, STG_TIME) Values(";
                foreach (XmlNode newsId in newsIdList)
                {
                    SQL += "'" + newsId["id"].InnerText + "',";
                    SQL += "" + newsId["seqNo"].InnerText + ",";
                }

                SQL += "'" + news["newsStatus"].InnerText + "',";

                XmlNodeList newsItemList = news.SelectNodes("newsItem");
                foreach (XmlNode newsItem in newsItemList)
                {
                    SQL += "'" + newsItem["languageId"].InnerText + "',";
                    if (newsItem["reSecCode"] != null)
                        SQL += "'" + newsItem["reSecCode"].InnerText + "',";
                    else
                        SQL += "' ',";
                    XmlNodeList releaseTimeList = newsItem.SelectNodes("releaseTime");
                    foreach (XmlNode releaseTime in releaseTimeList)
                    {
                        SQL += "TO_DATE('" + releaseTime["date"].InnerText + "','YYYYMMDD'),";
                        SQL += "" + releaseTime["time"].InnerText + ",";
                    }
                }

                XmlNodeList arabicFieldsList = news.SelectNodes("arabicFields");
                foreach (XmlNode arabicFields in arabicFieldsList)
                {
                    SQL += "'" + RevertSpecialCharacters(arabicFields["title_AR"].InnerText) + "',";
                }
                SQL += "TO_DATE('" + dt.ToString() + "','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM'))";
                DatabaseOperation(CommandType.Text, SQL, null);
                Console.WriteLine("Header : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }

            if (SQL != "") //RecordCount("Select Count(*) from COMPANIES_NEWS_DETAILS") > 0
            {
                OracleParameter pREFRESH = new OracleParameter("P_TABLE_NAMEs", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                pREFRESH.Value = "COMPANIES_NEWS";

                DatabaseOperation(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "REFRESH_VW_ALL", pREFRESH);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("From LoadNewsHeader -- " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void LoadNewsDetail(string text, DateTime dt)
    {
        try
        {

            //string fileName = "NewsDetail.xml";
            text = text.Replace("<arabicFields>", "<arabicFields>\n\t\t");

            //text = createXMLFile(fileName);
            //text = text.Replace("<arabicFields>", "<arabicFields>\n\t\t");
            XmlDocument _xmlDoc = LoadXMLDoc(text);


            string SQL = "";

            XmlNodeList newsList = _xmlDoc.SelectNodes("news/newsRep");
            if (newsList.Count > 0)
            {
                OracleParameter pTRUNCATE = new OracleParameter("P_TABLE_NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                pTRUNCATE.Value = "COMPANIES_NEWS_DETAILS";
                DatabaseOperation(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "TRUNCATE_TABLE", pTRUNCATE);
            }
            foreach (XmlNode news in newsList)
            {

                XmlNodeList newsIdList = news.SelectNodes("newsId");
                SQL = "Insert into Companies_news_details(NewsID_ID, NewsID_SEQNO, NewsText_1,NewsText_2,STG_TIME) Values(";
                foreach (XmlNode newsId in newsIdList)
                {
                    SQL += "" + newsId["id"].InnerText + ",";
                    SQL += "" + newsId["seqNo"].InnerText + ",";
                }
                XmlNodeList arabicFieldsList = news.SelectNodes("arabicFields");
                foreach (XmlNode arabicFields in arabicFieldsList)
                {
                   // Log(" Before Arabic Text Data -- :" + arabicFields["newsText_AR"].InnerText);
                    if (arabicFields["newsText_AR"].InnerText.Length > 4000)
                    {
                        SQL += "'" + RevertSpecialCharacters(arabicFields["newsText_AR"].InnerText.Substring(0, 3999)).Replace("\n",Environment.NewLine) + "',";
                        SQL += "'" + RevertSpecialCharacters(arabicFields["newsText_AR"].InnerText.Substring(3999, arabicFields["newsText_AR"].InnerText.Length)).Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine) + "',";
                        SQL += "TO_DATE('" + dt.ToString() + "','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM')";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SQL += "'" + RevertSpecialCharacters(arabicFields["newsText_AR"].InnerText).Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine) + "','',";
                        SQL += "TO_DATE('" + dt.ToString() + "','MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS PM')";

                    }

                    SQL += ")";
                    DatabaseOperation(CommandType.Text, SQL, null);
                    Console.WriteLine("Detail : " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                }
            }

            if (SQL != "") //RecordCount("Select Count(*) from COMPANIES_NEWS_DETAILS") > 0
            {
                OracleParameter pREFRESH = new OracleParameter("P_TABLE_NAMEs", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                pREFRESH.Value = "COMPANIES_NEWS_DETAILS";

                DatabaseOperation(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "REFRESH_VW_ALL", pREFRESH);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("From LoadNewsDetail -- " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void CloseApp()
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(0);    
    }

    protected static int GetMessageCount(MessageQueue q, string queueName)
    {
       var _messageQueue = new MessageQueue(queueName, QueueAccessMode.Peek);
       _messageQueue.Refresh();  //done to get the correct count as sometimes it sends 0
        var x = _messageQueue.GetMessageEnumerator2();
        int iCount = 0;
        while (x.MoveNext())
        {
           iCount++;
        }
        return iCount;
    }

    private static void DatabaseOperation(CommandType cmdType, string SQL, OracleParameter param)
    {
        string oracleConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["OracleConnectionString"];

        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = oracleConnectionString;
            con.Open();

            OracleCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandType = cmdType;
            command.CommandText = SQL;
            if (param != null)
                command.Parameters.Add(param);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            command.Dispose();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private static String RevertSpecialCharacters(string pValue)
    {
        string _retVal = String.Empty;
        _retVal = pValue.Replace("'", "''");

        return _retVal;
    }

    public static void Log(string Message)
    {
        // Create a writer and open the file:
        StreamWriter log;
        //C:\Software\MSMQ_New_News_Fix
        if (!File.Exists(@"C:\MSMQ_New_News_Fix\log.txt"))
        {
            log = new StreamWriter(@"C:\MSMQ_New_News_Fix\log.txt");
        }
        else
        {
            log = File.AppendText(@"C:\MSMQ_New_News_Fix\log.txt");
        }

        // Write to the file:
        log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + Message);
        // Close the stream:
        log.Close();
    }

    public static XmlDocument LoadXMLDoc(string xmlText)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            string xmlToLoad = ParseXMLFile(xmlText);
            doc.LoadXml(xmlToLoad);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("From LoadXMLDoc -- " + ex.Message);
        }
        return doc;
    }

    private static string ParseXMLFile(string xmlText)
    {
        StringBuilder formatedXML = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xmlText);
            while (xmlReader.Peek() >= 0)
                formatedXML.Append(ReplaceSpecialChars(xmlReader.ReadLine()) + "\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("From ParseXMLFile -- " + ex.Message);
        }
        return formatedXML.ToString();
    }

    private static string ReplaceSpecialChars(string xmlData)
    {
        try
        {
            //if (xmlData.Contains("objectRef")) return "<objectRef></objectRef>";
            int grtrPosAt = xmlData.IndexOf(">");
            int closePosAt = xmlData.IndexOf("</");
            int lenthToReplace = 0;
            if (grtrPosAt > closePosAt) return xmlData;

            lenthToReplace = (closePosAt <= 0 && grtrPosAt <= 0) ? xmlData.Length : (closePosAt - grtrPosAt) - 1;
            //get the string between xml element. e.g. <ContactName>Hanna Moos</ContactName>, 
            //you will get 'Hanna Moos'
            string data = xmlData.Substring(grtrPosAt + 1, lenthToReplace);
            string formattedData = data.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;")
                                       .Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("'", "&apos;");
            if (lenthToReplace > 0) xmlData = xmlData.Replace(data, formattedData);
            return xmlData;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log("From ReplaceSpecialChars -- " + ex.Message);
            return "";
        }
    }

}
}
```

How can i solve above issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from logic you are very correct that I should make windows service not timer service and Task schedule.

But my question was why It is login / log out frequently, which waste the resource of my Domain server. After intense investigation, I found that calling **QueueExits** is resource critical. Another thing what I found is that when you connect MSMQ queue you are login to share resource, which will login to Domain. As my code was running every 10-20 seconds it was wasting my Domain server resources.

For resolution, I make my MessageQueue object globally  in following way

```
private static MessageQueue mqNewsHeader = new MessageQueue(@".\q_ws_ampnewsheaderrep");
private static MessageQueue mqNewsDetails = new MessageQueue(@".\q_ws_ampnewsrep");
```

So it will create Once in the life of the Application and we will log in and log out only once. Then I will pass this object to the function as parameter. I see also that my MessageQueue count function was also resource critical, So I change it to following

```
protected static int GetMessageCount(MessageQueue q)
    {
       //var _messageQueue = new MessageQueue(queueName, QueueAccessMode.Peek);
       //_messageQueue.Refresh();  //done to get the correct count as sometimes it sends 0
       // var x = _messageQueue.GetMessageEnumerator2();
      int iCount = q.GetAllMessages().Count(); 
      // while (x.MoveNext())
       // {
       //    iCount++;
       // }

        return iCount;
    }
```

Hope this clear my answer and will help others also.

Answer (score 0):

Why not host your queue reader process in a windows service. This will continually poll the queue each 10 seconds.

Then use the windows scheduler to start/stop the service at relevant times to create your service window.

This means you won't need to do anything complicated in your scheduled task, and you won't be loading and unloading all the time.